# Extra space in the right of div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, removing-whitespace

I have extra space in the right side of my div. I have tried overflow:hidden and clear but i cannot get rid of it :(

This is my Html

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
#menu{
width: 800px;
height: auto;
border: none;
line-height:0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Navigation */ 

#nav {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
display: inline;   
}

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
}

#nav ul li{
padding: none;
margin: none;
border: thin black dashed;
}

#nav li a {
background: #7b7b7b;
border-right: 1px solid #474747;
color: #fff;
display: block;
float: left;
font: 400 18px 'Iceland', Tahoma, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 14.1%;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset .5px .5px 15px .5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
box-shadow: inset .5px .5px 15px .5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}

#nav li a:hover {
background: #bf0302;
}

nav li:last-child a {
border: none;
}

/* End of Navigation */
```

This is where the spacing is gone wrong. [image: Picture]
<sub>(source: [picturetrail.com](https://pic50.picturetrail.com/VOL403/9296584/21034325/405248088.jpg))</sub>

The thin yellow border is the menu div and the red one is nav.

Comment: `width: 14.1%;` is the culprit, that together with specific pixel values for padding means you will never get it "perfect". To fix it find the right pixel value for width

Comment: Is `#menu{width: 800px;}` responsive design?

Comment: So there's no solution? @kmkaplan Yes it's responsive, I have made width 100% in media query but the problem remains whether or not it is responsive. Because the white space is still there when the website is in full view.

Comment: @Andy But if i change it into px then it won't be right for different screen size.

Comment: seems like you are new with responsive navigation, you should check this: http://designshack.net/articles/css/code-a-responsive-navigation-menu/

Comment: I was actually following the very same tutorial and i had this problem ...

Comment: There are 2 soultions for your problem. Are you suing a fluid design or a media query design.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple you are hadding an 1px border to the rigth of the NAV LI A, so you need to compensate for this.

### So add this:

margin-rigth:-1px;

### Final CSS:

```
#nav li a {
   background: #7B7B7B;
   border-right: 1px solid #474747;
   color: white;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   font: 400 18px 'Iceland', Tahoma, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin-right: -1px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   width: 14.1%;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset .5px .5px 15px .5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
   box-shadow: inset .5px .5px 15px .5px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
```

### **[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/7nEcD/)** | **[Final Result](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/7nEcD/show/)**

Comment: Didn't work for me. It decreases the nav width which then increases the white space.

Comment: I am still trying to find a solution, gimme time :D | This one didn't work on small screens.